# query_post and wpdb returning different results

Tags: query-posts, wpdb, plugins

I am trying to get the woocommerce products by category.. When I query using the wpdb it gets the product correctly which exists in the backend products list. But when I query using the query_posts it gets another set of products that is not listed in the backend.

Why this discrepancy?

```
     global $post, $wpdb;                   


    $query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
    ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
    ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
    $childcond
    ORDER BY post_date DESC"; 

    if ($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {
        foreach ($postresults as $post) { 
              //process product item
        }
    }
```

using query_post

```
 query_posts('cat=1&showposts=-1');
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). From the Codex:

> query_posts() is the easiest, but not preferred or most efficient, way
>   to alter the main query that WordPress uses to display posts. It does
>   this by putting the main query to one side, and replacing it with a
>   new query. To clean up after a call to query_posts, make a call to
>   wp_reset_query(), and the original main query will be restored.
>
> It is strongly recommended that you use the pre_get_posts action
>   instead, and alter the main query by checking is_main_query

Second, your queries are different.

Compare the two. The query generated with those arguments-- `'cat=1&showposts=-1'`-- is:

```
SELECT 
  wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (
  wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1) 
) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Your hand-written query has two `LEFT JOIN`s not one `INNER JOIN`. Your query also has something called `$childcond`-- don't know what that is. It also has conditions for a particular `term_taxonomy.taxonomy` and there is no `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You're querying two different taxonomies- in your `wpbd` query you reference `product_cat`. in the call to `query_posts` you reference the default category taxonomy via the `cat` argument.

as an aside, you should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts`.

Comment: your suggestion is right..... query post uses the default category taxonomy  and wpdb reference the product_cat..But how it is able to fetch the product from default category..